# testing fallback function with truffle js

Tags: truffle, testing

SOLUTION BELOW

How do I go about testing the following fallback function:

```
function () public payable {
  revert();
}
```

being that the function does not have a function name, what do I need to do to test it? I tried using a function name that does not exist like this:

```
it("should not accept ETH deposits", async function() {
  let xferAmt = web3.toWei(0.5, "ether");
  await contract.dummyfunction({value: xferAmt}).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMThrow);
})
```

But truffle complains about the dummyfunction not being a function.

Thanks.
A.

SOLUTION

```
function () public {}
```

test:

```
it("should not accept ETH deposits", async function() {
  let xferAmt = 1;
  await contract.sendTransaction({value: xferAmt}).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMThrow);
});
```

Comment: you should use contract.send

Comment: What version of web3js are you using? 0.2 or 1.0?

Comment: @mirg - I tried contract.send and then got a strange error:

`new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]`

which is odd. as there is a only a revert

Comment: @Andromelus - whatever comes with truffle.. looks like "0.18.4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the fallback function:

```
function () public {
  // dont receive ether via fallback method (by not having 'payable' modifier on this function). 
}
```

See OpenZeppelin examples: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/HasNoEther.sol

And test it with `sendTransaction`:

```
it("...should reject sending ether directly to the contract.", async () => {
  instance = await Contract.deployed();
  await assertRevert(
    instance.sendTransaction(
      { from: myAddress, value: 1 }
    )
  );
});
```